# How to handle rotation in an HTML5 web app?

Tags: android, html, mobile, jquery-mobile, orientation

How to rotate the content of the HTML5 page when an orientation change occurs without having white area ?

I want to be able to scale the width to the new size as well.

The rotation should happen like the facebook mobile IOS & android app without showing any refreshes or white space while the rotation happens.

I built views with sencha,jquery-mobile all of them when loaded in the webview or phonegap api, displays the resizing while changing orientation.
Thanks.

Comment: It should be pretty fluid, if you follow, e.g. these guidelines: http://css3wizardry.com/2011/01/30/the-holy-grail-of-mobile-layout/ Check you mobile site in any web-kit browser when resizing quickly, if  white area is noticeable, you probably need to re-think your css and layout.

Answer (score 2):

add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" to the relevant Activity in your manifest. By setting this flag you tell Android to not destroy the Activity